# WriteConflictException not allowed in saveState - mongodb with replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

We use a MongoDB replica set, where after some time the primary set will throw the exception below and cannot recover from it. The error occurs only when we run the server in [Replicaset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) mode.

> Invariant failure !"WriteConflictException not allowed in saveState"
>   src/mongo/db/query/plan_yield_policy.cpp 95

After the above error, none of the MongoDB servers (in the replica set) are available and the following message is repeated in the mongo.log:

> REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] stepping down from primary, because a
>   new term has begun: 32

This is my server configuration:

Server 1:

- MongoDB (Percona version 3.2.4-1.0rc2)
- MongoDB Arbiter (Percona version 3.2.4-1.0rc2)

Server 2:

- MongoDB (Percona version 3.2.4-1.0rc2)

Comment: Have you tried the same thing with official MongoDB release? (might be a Percona bug). Also, what version of the client are you using?

Comment: No we haven't tried without the Percona. We're using Mongoose 4.4.17

Comment: Two immediate comments: firstly, you should really be running the arbiter on a different server, in case Server 1 goes completely offline leaving only a single node on Server 2. Secondly, what is the health of the replicaset after the primary has failed? You can find out with the [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) call.